# Why store compute field odoo10 is null in database

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I would like to store field `tot_comp_survey` into table `survey_survey` in odoo.

With this code:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class Survey(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'survey.survey'

    tot_comp_survey = fields.Integer("Number of completed surveys", compute="_compute_survey_statistic", store=True)
```

`_compute_survey_statistic`:

```
    @api.multi
    def _compute_survey_statistic(self):
        UserInput = self.env['survey.user_input']

        sent_survey = UserInput.search([('survey_id', 'in', self.ids), ('type', '=', 'link')])
        start_survey = UserInput.search(['&', ('survey_id', 'in', self.ids), '|', ('state', '=', 'skip'), ('state', '=', 'done')])
        complete_survey = UserInput.search([('survey_id', 'in', self.ids), ('state', '=', 'done')])

        for survey in self:
            survey.tot_sent_survey = len(sent_survey.filtered(lambda user_input: user_input.survey_id == survey))
            survey.tot_start_survey = len(start_survey.filtered(lambda user_input: user_input.survey_id == survey))
            survey.tot_comp_survey = len(complete_survey.filtered(lambda user_input: user_input.survey_id == survey))
```

and the results like this:
[image]

store field that I want exactly store in database, but when I apply this code into database with 1000 rows, `tot_comp_survey` is null in database.
[image]

Could anyone help me, please?

Is there something missing?

Just additional information: when I upgrade this code in small database (only 8 rows data) upgrade proccess time is normal, but when I do it in big database (1000 and more rows data) the upgrade proccess is very slow.

Comment: I not run ./manage.py. I just copy my code to live server, restart service, and upgrade module.

Comment: This code is run well in database with small data (compute field is not null), but I get null when this code has implemented in database with big data.

Comment: can you show the `_compute_survey_statistic` or part of it

Comment: ok Please check the changes I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically its computed when needed. Have you tried to access any of the records?

Try to add `@api.depends('user_input_ids', 'user_input_ids.input_type', 'user_input_ids.state')` to the function header. Then Odoo knows when to change the values.

You may need to add some `One2many` fields

Comment: I've tried to add `@api.depend()` method but I get Internal Server Error. By the way `_compute_survey_statistic` is default functions from odoo

Comment: I have not used Odoo 10. Usually its enough to add store=True. Does line like that gives also the error `@api.depends('user_input_ids', 'user_input_ids.input_type', 'user_input_ids.state')`